# Issues displaying embedded Google map on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, google-maps

I created a 'My Map' in google and embedded it into my wordpress site.
The map displays fine on desktop. On android it displays, but a box with all the locations hides most of the map and it doesn't seem to be responsive. On an iphone the map simply doesn't display.
Is there any code I need to add to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: http://camdencab.ibtsonline.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

you need to look  on to this (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). It provides all the steps you need setup google map on android. For iphone,  i didn't familiar with that.